# CakePhp: Issue with model and table name

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I have StatsController.php with

```
class StatsController extends AppController {
    public function edit($id = null) {
        var_dump($this->Stat);
    }
}
```

I have StatModel.php with

```
class Stat extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'tips';
    // ....
}
```

When I try to save my data, my initial error is:

> Missing Database Table | Error: Table stats for model Stat was not found in datasource default.

What am I doing wrong, thanks.

Here is the var_dump:

```
object(AppModel)[26]
  public 'useDbConfig' => string 'default' (length=7)
  public 'useTable' => string 'stats' (length=5)
  public 'id' => null
  public 'data' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'schemaName' => null
  public 'table' => string 'stats' (length=5)
  public 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
  protected '_schema' => null
  public 'validate' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'validationErrors' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'validationDomain' => null
  public 'plugin' => null
  public 'name' => string 'Stat' (length=4)
  public 'alias' => string 'Stat' (length=4)
  public 'tableToModel' => 
    array (size=1)
      'stats' => string 'Stat' (length=4)
  public 'cacheQueries' => boolean false
  public 'belongsTo' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'hasOne' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'hasMany' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'hasAndBelongsToMany' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'actsAs' => null
  public 'Behaviors' => 
    object(BehaviorCollection)[27]
      public 'modelName' => string 'Stat' (length=4)
      protected '_methods' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_mappedMethods' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_enabled' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_loaded' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'defaultPriority' => int 10
  public 'whitelist' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'cacheSources' => boolean true
  public 'findQueryType' => null
  public 'recursive' => int 1
  public 'order' => null
  public 'virtualFields' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected '_associationKeys' => 
    array (size=4)
      'belongsTo' => 
        array (size=6)
          0 => string 'className' (length=9)
          1 => string 'foreignKey' (length=10)
          2 => string 'conditions' (length=10)
          3 => string 'fields' (length=6)
          4 => string 'order' (length=5)
          5 => string 'counterCache' (length=12)
      'hasOne' => 
        array (size=6)
          0 => string 'className' (length=9)
          1 => string 'foreignKey' (length=10)
          2 => string 'conditions' (length=10)
          3 => string 'fields' (length=6)
          4 => string 'order' (length=5)
          5 => string 'dependent' (length=9)
      'hasMany' => 
        array (size=11)
          0 => string 'className' (length=9)
          1 => string 'foreignKey' (length=10)
          2 => string 'conditions' (length=10)
          3 => string 'fields' (length=6)
          4 => string 'order' (length=5)
          5 => string 'limit' (length=5)
          6 => string 'offset' (length=6)
          7 => string 'dependent' (length=9)
          8 => string 'exclusive' (length=9)
          9 => string 'finderQuery' (length=11)
          10 => string 'counterQuery' (length=12)
      'hasAndBelongsToMany' => 
        array (size=12)
          0 => string 'className' (length=9)
          1 => string 'joinTable' (length=9)
          2 => string 'with' (length=4)
          3 => string 'foreignKey' (length=10)
          4 => string 'associationForeignKey' (length=21)
          5 => string 'conditions' (length=10)
          6 => string 'fields' (length=6)
          7 => string 'order' (length=5)
          8 => string 'limit' (length=5)
          9 => string 'offset' (length=6)
          10 => string 'unique' (length=6)
          11 => string 'finderQuery' (length=11)
  protected '_associations' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'belongsTo' (length=9)
      1 => string 'hasOne' (length=6)
      2 => string 'hasMany' (length=7)
      3 => string 'hasAndBelongsToMany' (length=19)
  public '__backAssociation' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public '__backInnerAssociation' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public '__backOriginalAssociation' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public '__backContainableAssociation' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected '_insertID' => null
  protected '_sourceConfigured' => boolean false
  public 'findMethods' => 
    array (size=6)
      'all' => boolean true
      'first' => boolean true
      'count' => boolean true
      'neighbors' => boolean true
      'list' => boolean true
      'threaded' => boolean true
  protected '_eventManager' => null
  protected '_validator' => null
```

Comment: Please clarify: "it seems my model is not used".  What are you actually trying in your 'edit' action, and what's not working?  Also, what version of CakePHP are you in?  And, why do you have "blablallalsaddasdasdasd" in your model.

Comment: @Dave at this time in my edit function I have only this code, fine. When I say 'my model is not used', I mean it seems to not be loaded because I have no php errors (in my code I put wrong stuff to generate an error). If everything was ok, it should break the code but it's not the case. I hope it's more clear. Version used is 2.4.4

Comment: Instead of asking a question to a problem that doesn't exist, try giving us the actual problem.  Like... when I try to do a find() it's giving an error, or returning the wrong data...etc.  You're basically saying "here's some code that has no problems - what's the problem?"  Answer - nothing.

Comment: Well ok. My error is when I try to save my datas, my initial error is: Missing Database Table | Error: Table stats for model Stat was not found in datasource default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have StatModel.php with

Rename the file `StatModel.php` to `Stat.php` and ensure it's located in your `Model` folder. Model files are not appended with the word `Model`. I know, it's inconsistent with controllers but I didn't write Cake :)

> When I call /stats/edit, it seems my model is not used, I didn't get any errors and also I am not able to change the table name (I want to use tips table)

CakePHP couldn't find the `Stat.php` file in your models folder so it automatically creates a fake model. Using the model name as a pattern it looks for a `stats` table.

Comment: I've made this mistake many times. I wish there was a feature to disable auto models in Cake. Wait til you have to trace down a failed association.

Comment: Fake -> AppModel instance. Which can be confirmed with `debug (get_class ($this-> Stat));`

Comment: Mathew - You can use your app model constructor to check the class and throw an exception to highlight such errors

Comment: @AD7six what would `get_class` return? "AppModel" or "Model"?

Comment: @AD7six oh that's a great idea!

Answer (score -2):

I guess the inflector can't resolve Stats to Stat properly. Don't use abbreviations, why not statistics? Why not TipsController at all if you deal with the tips table?

However, if you want to use that model try:

```
public $uses = array('Stat');
```

in your controller to explicitly set that model.

Comment: it's already loading the model, or it wouldn't successfully debug `$this->Stat`, right?

Comment: I didn't try but the other answer fixes my issue. Thanks btw.

Comment: -1 there is nothing wrong with inflections here, or in using abbreviations.

Comment: @Dave *before* you edited his question it has shown the debug output of the model object: It was AppModel. This means it was *not* loading the correct model and that's why I *guessed* the cause.

Comment: my bad - put it back in.